The Haar measure on a product of a positive-measure set and an unbounded subgroup
Let $G$ be a locally compact group with left Haar measure $\lambda$, $A\subseteq G$ with $0<\lambda(A)$ and $H\leq G$ a closed and non-compact subgroup. Must $\lambda(A\cdot H)=\infty$? It is not hard to see this for a unimodular group (in that case $H$ need not even be a subgroup) but I can't figure out whether this is true in general.

At least $\lambda(A)>0$ is necessary for the statement to hold.

Right, of course, I meant that and not the upper bound. Edited. Is it sufficient?

Another little quibble: compact topological groups $G$ can have non-compact (but, obviously, not closed) subgroups $H$. E.g., $G$ is a two-torus, and $H$ an irrationally wound real line on it. So, I think, you'd need a hypothesis to exclude this kind of thing...

Thank you, I of course mean a closed $H$. Edited.

Alright, I figured it out. It's true. You can arrange for infinitely many distinct elements $h_n\in H$, each with $\Delta(h^{-1}_n)\leq 1$, such that $Ah_n, Ah_m$ are disjoint for $n \neq m$. This gives an infinite collection of disjoint subsets of $A\cdot H$, all of whose Haar measures are bounded uniformly from below by a fixed positive number.
